# How do i create page.properties file for Bonitasoft

Tags: windows, bonita

Please How do i create file with encoding `ISO 8859-1` files on windows Machine? I am kind of lost here and i actually don't know where to start.

I wanted to use Notepad or Notepad++ to create a pages.properties file for `Bonitasoft` as i built a REST api so i can use to test the `REST (Webservice was coded in groovy Rest)` and later on use in my UI designer, I built using the Java and `Bonitasoft` Jar files, but when i click save as , i only see for `UTF-8` How do i go about it.

Answer (score 0):

page.properties file in Bonita will be read by Bonita Engine, a Java application, and so need to use, as you find out, ISO 8859-1 character encoding (see Java [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class documentation for the details).

When creating a file using Notepad++ you can choose the character sets from the "Encoding" menu -> "Character sets" -> "Western Europe" -> "8859-1". For encoding you should select "ANSI" from the "Encoding" menu. "ANSI" should be compatible with "8859-1".